# MySql query performance puzzle

Tags: mysql, performance

I've got two queries that seem more or less identical, but they have very different performance and I can't figure out why.  Basically, I've got a large table (6M rows) of blogs that I need to lock and process.  Originally, the query looked like this:

```
insert into bloglock
select b.id, [lockid], CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
from blog b
left join bloglock bl
on b.id=bl.blogid
WHERE
State=[somestate]
AND
bl.BlogId IS NULL
```

The semantics of this are: 
Lock a blog by making an entry in the bloglock table consisting of the blog id, a lock id, and the current timestamp.  But only do this if the blog state is what we want to lock, and if the blog isn't already locked (bl.BlogId IS NULL).

This query runs very fast, around 5/100ths of a second.

But then I had to force certain blogs to be processed before others.  So I added an integer priority field, an index on this field, and changed the query to:

```
insert into bloglock
select b.id, [lockid], CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
from blog b
left join bloglock bl
on b.id=bl.blogid
WHERE
State=[somestate]
AND
bl.BlogId IS NULL
order by Priority desc
LIMIT 100;
```

Same as before, except that it gets the first 100 hundred in order of priority.  This query is dog slow, taking around 30 seconds to execute.  I can accept that.  But the puzzle is that I rewrote it to this:

```
insert into bloglock
select *
from
(select b.id, [lockid], CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
from blog b
left join bloglock bl
on b.id=bl.blogid
WHERE
State=[somestate]
AND
bl.BlogId IS NULL
order by Priority desc
LIMIT 100) InnerQuery;
```

And now it runs as fast as before.  I don't get this.  It seems like the same query to me, and certainly I would think it would be the same to the optimizer, but instead there's a 60-fold difference in performance.  What's going on here?

Comment: I don't understand it well enough to contribute an actual answer, but I think the location of your `LIMIT` clause is what's doing the job - you're filtering down to 100 at the end in the first case, and to 100 at the beginning in the second (drastically reducing the amount of work to do).

Comment: And have you looked at the explain plans of the two queries?

Comment: @Luke: I don't see how that could be, given that the parentheses group the work the same way in both cases.

Comment: yeah - that's why I prefaced it with "I don't understand it well enough" :). I second HLGEM's advice - take a look at what explain tells you.

Comment: @HLGEM: I confess I'm not sure how to do that.  You can put EXPLAIN before select, but not before INSERT.  And the select statement runs fine by itself, so that wouldn't help.  How can you profile a combined insert into ... select construct like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no logical reason why the third query should be faster than the second.  I believe that you have probably encountered a bug in the query optimization of MySQL.  You might consider filing a bug report about this for the MySQL developers.

Comment: This is certainly how it seems to me, but I'm reluctant to file a bug report without being *really* sure I'm not missing something dumb.

Comment: You're definitely not missing anything dumb.  There's a very small chance that you might be missing something very subtle and specific to MySQL, but even that seems iffy.  Generally, most RDBMSs optimize queries by transforming them into relational algebra and then considering different ways of implementing the relational algebra expressions to figure out which will be fasted in the situation.  In some cases, having an outer query could result in some rewriting which would speed things.  But in this case, the outer query is trivial and no new rewriting could occur.

Comment: Thanks for the reality check.  I'll see about telling MySql about it.